# Bottom overloaded by 27 pixels in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm the details page. This works fine for me. When I display in landscape mode then I get an error Bottom overloaded by 27 pixels.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK8Am.png)

Code:

```
body: SafeArea(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: kPadding8,
        ),
        height: 43,
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: kPadding20,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Harga',
                    style: kRalewayRegular.copyWith(
                      color: kGrey85,
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * 2.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical! * 0.5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Rp. 25.000.000 / Tahun',
                    style: kRalewayMedium.copyWith(
                      color: kBlack,
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * 4,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                debugPrint('Telah Disewa');
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 43,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    kBorderRadius10,
                  ),
                  gradient: kLinearGradientBlue,
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: kPadding24,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Sewa',
                    style: kRalewaySemibold.copyWith(
                      color: kWhite,
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * 4,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Still the same, the complete code can be seen via the link next to this.
https://pastebin.com/DSWbb28h

Comment: Try to work with flex layout. Wrap your child widgets with the Expanded-widget and set the flex factor.

Answer (score 0):

For each **container** in your Screen remove height
then you can see which component is overflowing,
Better try to don't specify Height for Container so it will take the height of child widget